How to tell if a ListItem has any text that is italicized?
I'm trying to write some code in google app scripts to detect if a ListItem has any italicized styling. listItem.getAttributes()[DocumentApp.Attribute.ITALIC] will only return true if the entire listItem is italicized, and null if some or none of the text is italicized. Is there any way to get true if even a single character has italicized style?

In your situation, how about the following sample script?
Sample script:
Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your Google Document and save the script.
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const listItems = body.getListItems();
  listItems.forEach(e => {
    const textObj = e.editAsText();
    const text = textObj.getText();
    const isItalic = [...Array(text.length)].some((_, i) => textObj.isItalic(i));
    console.log({ isItalic, text });
  });
}

Testing:
When this script is used in the following sample Document,

the following result is obtained by console.log({ isItalic, text }). In this sample, text of sample text 1 and 3 of sample text 3 are set as the italic type.
{ isItalic: true, text: 'sample text 1' }

{ isItalic: false, text: 'sample text 2' }

{ isItalic: true, text: 'sample text 3' }

You can see that sample text 1 and sample text 3 return true.
Note:

In this sample script, all list items are checked. If you want to check the 1st list items, as a simple modification, please modify listItems.forEach(e => { to [listItems[0]].forEach(e => {.

Reference:

isItalic(offset) of Class Text


worked perfectly, thank you!

@Howard Zimmerman Thank you for relpying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
